# Render data in EJS template using Mongoose .find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating a simple CRUD app. The thing is: it's connected to MongoDB just fine, I can save data normally and also delete it. But I can't seem to find it!
I don't know if the error is in EJS or in the back-end.

This is the error:

[lessons.forEach is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4OhT.png)

And this is the back-end code:

```js
//search lessons
exports.searchLesson = (req, res) => {
    let searchField = req.body.searchField;
    if (req.query.id) {
        const id = req.query.id;

        Lesson.findById(id)
            .then(data => {
                if (!data) {
                    res.status(404).send({
                        message: 'User not found'
                    })
                } else {
                    res.send(data)
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(500).send({
                    message: 'Error retrieving lesson with id ' + id
                })
            });

    } else {
        Lesson.find({
                teacher: searchField
            })
            .then(lesson => {
                res.render('searchLesson.ejs', {
                    lessons: lesson
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(500).send({
                    message: err.message || "Error occured while retrieving lesson information"
                });
            });
    }
};
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel Moura Once try **`lesson`** instead of `lessons` On Front end This is Type Error it means we misspelled something we have to correct on both side in the controller and on ejs file...